# Show Only the Lowest Price woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, elementor

I used this code to show the lowest price among product variants in my shop. https://www.styl-bruk.eu/ Unfortunately, I noticed that the code does not show the lowest price on the single product page, it works only on the shop page, can anyone help me, what did I do wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS3v6.png)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'wpglorify_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'wpglorify_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
 
function wpglorify_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
 
// Main Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
$price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
 
// Sale Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
sort( $prices );
$saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
 
    if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
$price = '<del>'. $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price .  '</ins>';
}
return $price;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_show_variation_price',      function() { return TRUE;});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the below code, and it worked in both single and archive product page.

Since you are using `woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html` and `woocommerce_variable_price_html` hooks too, maybe it's because of your active theme or a plugin that your code doesn't work as expected.

```php
// from https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-only-lowest-prices-in-woocommerce-variable-products/.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'custom_variable_price_range', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variable_price_range', 10, 2 );
function custom_variable_price_range( $price_html, $product ) {

    $prefix     = 'From';
    $min_price  = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );
    $suffix = $product->get_price_suffix( $price = '', $qty = 1 );
    return $prefix . ' ' . wc_price( $min_price ) . $suffix;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I've tested your code, worked in both single and archive product page.

There are also some plugins to achieve this:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-only-lowest-prices-in-woocommerce-variable-products/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-variable-product-price-range-show-only-lowest-price-in-variable-products/